# Duda con diagrama de entidades para app

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy creando una app y ando medio enredado pensando en una nueva funcionalidad. El contexto es el siguiente:

- Actualmente un usuario puede crear eventos, por lo que cuando se crea un evento este se relaciona al usuario por medio del campo `admin_id`. Pero ahora un evento podra crear publicaciones y ahi viene mi gran duda.

Sabiendo que el usuario es dueño de un evento, cuando se crea una publicacion para el evento, este estaria relacionado por medio de el `event_id` o tambien debe existir un campo `user_id` dentro de la tabla `event_publications`?

Adjunto un ejemplo de la relacion entre entidades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es necesario, pero ¿es conveniente?. La redundancia no es demasiado problema, la inconsistencia sí.

Comment: hola!, gracias. Por lo que tendria que tener event_id nada mas ya que es una publicacion del evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo depende de la lógica de negocio.

- Es probable que el usuario de la publicación sea distinto al administrador del evento. En ese caso, necesitas ambas columnas.
- Si el usuario de la publicación siempre será el administrador del evento, entonces no necesitas la columna en la tabla de publicaciones.

Comment: hola, mm claro en este caso el que creo el evento es el admin del evento, por lo que la columna seria solo event_id nada mas no?

Comment: Pero una cosa es el evento y otra las publicaciones. Esto es algo que tienes que revisar con los encargados del negocio, no en internet.

Comment: jejeje la app es mia, yo la ando desarrollando

Answer (score 0):

Sólo necesitas el `event_id` en `Event_publication`. Con los joins puedes hacer las consultas que necesites. Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener registros con los nombres de los usuarios, el `id` del evento y el contenido de la publicación, haces:

```
SELECT name, event.id, content FROM user INNER JOIN event ON user.id = admin_id
INNER JOIN event_publication ON event.id = event_id
```